# Trying to search a CSV for a barcode value, to then rename files based on cells relating to that barcode

Tags: python, csv, search, rename

I have a bunch of files in a directory named by a barcode, then image number. (Barcode_01.jpg, Barcode_02.jpg) etc.

I'm looking to search a CSV based on the Barcode portion of the filename, then when the barcode is found, to rename the file based on information in the row for that barcode.

Example:

```
files in directory:

123456789_01.jpg
123456789_02.jpg
012345_01.jpg
012345_02.jpg
98765_01.jpg
98765_02.jpg
```

The barcodes relate to a range of products, which, in the CSV also have a product code and a colour code that I need to rename the files to in the format {product code in CSV}*{colour code in CSV}*{image number of original filename}.jpg

Effectively looking to replace the barcode value, with the product and colour code, retaining the image number.

So I've used splitext to parse the filenames and simplify them from their originals which works just fine.

I've also looked at xlwings and csv to search for values within the spreadsheet or CSV But I can't seem to get them to work together.

The code I have for renaming the files was modified after watching some corey shaeffer tutorials

```
import os
os.chdir('[FILE DIRECTORY I NEED TO RENAME]')

for f in os.listdir('[FILE DIRECTORY I NEED TO RENAME]'):
f_name,f_ext = (os.path.splitext(f))
f_sku = (f_name.split('_')[0])
f_num = (f_name[-2:])

n_name = ('{}_{}{}'.format(f_sku,f_num,f_ext))
os.rename(f, n_name)
```

I have also looked to open with dictreader and search for the barcode in column 8 of the CSV, however i'm very new to how this all works and can't seem to get any results worth writing home about.

I tried to do the following to see if I could get it to at least return some values on a search:

```
import csv
import os


for f in os.listdir('[file directory]'):
f_name,f_ext = (os.path.splitext(f))
f_sku = (f_name.split('_')[0])
f_num = (f_name[-2:])

with open('[file directory]','r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

for row in csv_file:
    if row[8] == f_sku:
        print(row)
```

I have defined the search string as 'f_sku' from above - which would be the part of the filename that i'm looking for in the CSV. Which is about as far as I can get.

EDIT: I was getting bugs with the directories and issues where once the script was run, it wouldn't run again with a new image set in the directory as the split was looking for the wrong things, for whatever reason it was buggy.

So I peeled back and used the file parsing I had on a previous script. I also defined the directory to make it clearer.

```
import os
import csv

ImageDir = "IMAGE DIR"
RenDir = "RENAMED FILES DIR"

for f in os.listdir(ImageDir):
  f_name,f_ext = (os.path.splitext(f))
  f_bcode = (f_name.split('_')[0])
  f_num = (f_name[-2:])

## FINDING THE NEW FILENAME FROM THE BARDCODES CSV

   with open('CSV DIR', 'r') as 
csv_file:
      csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
      for row in csv_reader:
          if row[8] == f_bcode:
               n_name = row[0]+"_"+row[5]+"_"+f_num+f_ext
               os.rename(ImageDir + f,ImageDir + n_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume `given_name` is the name you are given from `f` in your code. Your code works for certain files, but not all. ALL files have their extension after the "." and all YOUR files are separated by an underscore. Hence, you split the given name by a "." and underscore to render each different part of the filename.

```
import os
import csv

for f in os.listdir('[FILE DIRECTORY I NEED TO RENAME]'):
  given_name = f

  f_name, f_ext = given_name.split(".")
  f_sku, f_num = f_name.split("_")

  with open('CSV File', 'r') as csv_file:
      csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
      for row in csv_reader:
          if row[8] == f_sku:
              n_name = row[0]+"_"+row[5]+"_"+f_num+"."+f_ext
```

Comment: My apologies - I have updated that portion to split prior to the underscore - as it had changed from what I was using it for originally.

So the split is now the barcode which will be prior to the underscore on all files.

I need to use that split value to search the CSV and then write a new filename based on two values in that row, being the product and colour code. The image numbers and underscore need to be retained.

Comment: @Graham how is your CSV structured?

Comment: Prod Code,Brand,Brand Name,Product Type,Prod Name,Clr Code,Clr Name,Size,SKU Barcode

so im looking in column reference [8] and trying to rename the file to column [0]_[6]_01.jpg

Comment: @Graham I believe this code should work for your purposes. It iterates over each row in the CSV file. If that row is referrencing the specific file, it will get Product Code, Color Code, and the original number and extension. It will then combine the information for the new name.

Comment: thank you so much for taking a look at this. Is it safe to assume that the "for f in os.listdir" can still be used to make sure all files in the directory are searched for in the CSV and renamed accordingly? The files will then be parsed correctly for the barcode search. I'm seeing a syntax error on if row[8] = f_sku: "invalid syntax"

Comment: the 'r' needed to be defined and the syntax required another = symbol - but that pulled the correct information. Thanks so much for your help - I just need it to function for all files in that directory now and i'm all set - so i'm testing a few more things :)

Comment: @Graham sorry for the small, but important errors. Glad I could help!

Comment: it's greatly appreciated. I don't suppose you would be able to shed some light on how this could be done for all files in that directory as opposed to pointing out one in particular? As these files will change all the time (in the specified folder).

When I entered the os.rename(f,n_name) it tells me there is no such directory, however if i just print(n_name) it returns one value printed with the correct informtation.

Comment: @Graham I edited the code to work with all files in a directory. Check it now.

Comment: Fantastic! I added print(n_name) after to test and it shows the full list of changed filenames,which is great, however when I add os.rename(f,n_name) it returns an "OSError [Error 2] No such file or directory" flag. Strange, given it's obvously been able to find the files in the directory and print new names, it just can't change them?

Comment: I have updated the original post. I went back and did some digging when I started seeing a couple of syntax errors and tried a couple of workarounds. Thank you so much for your help - I wish I could tell you how much time this is going to save me. Greatly appreciated.